# What happened to the double elimination in the Over the Top tournament?

Tags: plot-explanation, over-the-top

Hawk loses once in the arm wrestling tournament and over and over we hear it is double elimination.  But Bull at the end has never lost, and once Hawk beats him... boom movie is over.  I know the movie is terrible but did I miss something?

Comment: The movie is terrible?  WUT?  It's classic 80's Stallone!  Robert Loggia as the bad guy and the theme song by Kenny Loggins along with the awesome movie poster displaying Stallone's huge arm!  C'mon!  It's awesome!! ;)  Also...To answer your question, I believe that the double elimination doesn't apply to the final match.

Comment: @steelersquirrel - I just watched the last 30 mins - my kids were intrigued and wouldn't let me change it - so maybe it was bad.  I don't remember them saying the finals weren't double elimination...  but maybe I didn't hear it right.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**The double elimination did not apply to the final match**.

The announcer states that through the semi-finals, it is double elimination:

> We continue with our semifinaI series of matches. This is a doubIe
>   eIimination tournament. Any competitor who loses twice out of the
>   eight on these four tabIes...

So, throughout the competition, it was double elimination until they reached the final match.  The final match is sudden death, which means that the winner wins the tournament automatically:

> Ladies and gentIemen, the finaI match.The winner here tonight will
>   walk out with the world cup, a $250,000 truck from the VoIvo White
>   company, $100,000 in cash, and the title of arm wrestling worId
>   champion.

Comment: OK well this is the right answer but to me it is a screen play gaffe.  When you are in a tournament and the double elimination ends at some point you explicitly say "From here on it is single elimination".  To me "the winner here tonight..." could still mean that Bull needs to be between twice.   Stallone is a dumbass.

Comment: I also theorized that they could have given him a loss for the nose punch, but this makes more sense.